nginx.conf best way to handle multiple if conditions within location?
I want to authorize the user based on his email without it getting super messy. Is there a better way to do this?
http {
  map $http_user $user {
    default $http_user;
  }
  
  server {
      ...
      
      location ~ ^(/deployments/).*(xxx).* {
          set $allow 0;
          if($user = "abc@x.com" || $user = "bcd@x.com" || $user = "cde@x.com"){
             set $allow 1;
          }
          
          if($allow = 0){
             return 403 {error: you are not authorized}
          }
      }

      location ~ ^(/deployments/).*(yyy).* {
          set $allow 0;
          if($user = "abc@x.com" || $user = "bcd@x.com" || $user = "cde@x.com"){
             set $allow 1;
          }
          
          if($allow = 0){
             return 403 {error: you are not authorized}
          }
      }
  
  }

}

Is there a better way to do this?
I tried the above code but it doesn't work

You code will not work because of the way if functions when inside a location.
You can use a map instead, which can be cascaded from your existing map.
For example:
map $http_user $user {
    default $http_user;
}
map $user $reject {
    default 1;
    abc@x.com 0;
    bcd@x.com 0;
    cde@x.com 0;
}

server {
    ...      
    location ... {
        if ($reject) {
            return 403 '{"error": "you are not authorized"}'
        }
    }
}

Expressions containing brace characters must be quoted, also JSON strings should be quoted.

If you have ngx_http_auth_request_module installed, you can leverage auth_request directive to avoid if block in each location:
map $http_user  $allow {
    abc@x.com   1;
    bcd@x.com   1;
    cde@x.com   1;
    default     0;
}

server {

    location /foo {
        auth_request /_internal/auth;
        ...
    }

    location /bar {
        auth_request /_internal/auth;
        ...
    }

    location = /_internal/auth {
        internal;
        if ($allow = 1) {
            return 200;
        }
        return 403;
    }

    location = /_internal/error/403 {
        internal;
        default_type application/json;
        return 403 '{"error": "you are not authorized"}';
    }

    error_page 403 /_internal/error/403;
}

